# MVC3: Button action on the same view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, button, view

i wish to change the inner html of a view on button click but maintain the view. I know how to change the html content of a div in javascript, but how can I have the action of the button not return a different view?

My buton looks like

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onchange="myfunc()"/>
```

where myfunc() is the function in Javascript changing the div content.

Comment: Are you looking for [`Ajax.ActionLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)? or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I am look for a button action that will help me stay on the current page and set of a <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a link to render content using ajax (and hopefully using razor) you can do something like the following:

First, setup the action to render the content partially. this can be done a few ways, but I'll keep with the logic in the action (and make it callable directly or by ajax):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(SomeModel model)
{
  /* build view */
  return Request.IsAjaxRequest() ? PartialView(model) : Wiew(model);
}
```

Next, setup a container in your page where the content will be populated along with the form you're looking to submit. If you want the form to disappear on a save, wrap it in the container. Otherwise, keep the container separated. In the below example, the from will submit and on success it'll come back, otherwise the new content will appear in its place:

```
<div id="ajaxContentPlaceholder">
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ajaxContentPlaceholder" })) {
      <!-- form elements -->
      <input type="submit" value="save" />
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. On a side note, say I have a form where controls are added dynamically and I want to remove these dynamic controls added to the form on button click. How can I do this in a javascript. I hae a button tag but it still acts as a submit button after added the onClick attribute to it.

Comment: @jpo: Can you create a jsfiddle.net of the form and then explain "on click, I'd like controls x, y & z to be removed"?